# Integrating speech recognition in bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I wanted to integrate speech recognition in bot framework.Is there any appropriate blog which can help me from scratch ! Please recommend if any!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for just documentation, here are some good places to start

- [Start building bots with the Bot Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-builder-overview-getstarted)
- [Getting Started with Building Bots with Microsoft's Bot Framework](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/microsoft-bot-framework-getting-started)
- [Getting Started with Microsoft Bot Framework](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/)